# when like icon is red, post to api

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have been trying to create a like icon in which am declaring a likepress function that should post to api everytime user clicks on it and then change the state to red,

This is my full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//Import React
import { AppRegistry, View, Dimensions, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Viewport } from '@skele/components'
//Import Basic React Native Component
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const PRE_TRIGGER_RATIO = -0.4;
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Videos extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = { header: null }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        data: [],
        likeIcon: 'white',

    };

  }



  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('some url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            data: responseJson,
          },
          console.log(responseJson)
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }

    likePress = async() => {
      if (this.state.likeIcon == 'white') {    
          fetch('some url' , {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                  like: this.state.product._id
              })
              .catch(error => {

                console.error(error);
              })
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {

              this.setState({ likeIcon: 'red', data: result })
              console.log(_id,'id')
            console.log(result,JSON.stringify({
              like: this.state.product._id
          }))
          }).catch(error => {
            alert(error);
            console.error(error);
          })
      }
  }



  render() {

    const ViewportAwareVideo = Viewport.Aware(Video);
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View >
         <StatusBar hidden />
        {/* <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', position:'absolute', zIndex:1}}> */}
        <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top:10,
        left:10,
        zIndex:100
    }}>

    <Icon
        name="shopping-cart"
        size={24}
        style={{ paddingRight: 40}}
        color="white"
    />

</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top:10,
        left:40,
        zIndex:100
    }}
    >
    <Icon
        name="user-circle"
        size={24}
        style={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
        color="white"
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
            {/* </View> */}

        <FlatList
        data={this.state.data.product}
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style = {{alignContent: 'stretch'}} >

      <ViewportAwareVideo

          source={{ uri: item.urlVid }}
          resizeMode = "cover"
          preTriggerRatio={PRE_TRIGGER_RATIO} 
          retainOnceInViewport={false}  
          style={{width: width, height:height}}
          innerRef={ref => this._videoRef = ref}
          onViewportEnter={() => this._videoRef.play()}
          onViewportLeave={() => this._videoRef.stop()} 
        />

         <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                top: '50%',
                right: 10,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.likePress}
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.state.likeIcon}

                />
              </TouchableOpacity>


              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="share" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="whatsapp" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="download" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                flexDirection: 'column',

                top: '90%',
                left: 10,
              }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Product')}>
                <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, color: 'white' }}>
                  {item.title} - {item.price}
                </Text>



              </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>

        </View> 


        )}

        keyExtractor={ item => item.id}
      />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

However, on doing this am able to fetch the main api but the likepress api does not seem to work, it is throwing me an error which is :

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.product._id')
```

Please tell me where am going wrong

Comment: Have you declared `product` variable in your state ? Can you please how it look like ?

Comment: Where exactly is `likePress` defined?

Comment: Can you post your full code? Where are you setting `product` in state?

Comment: likepress is an async function declared, and then called inside like icon @James

Comment: I will post the full code, please tell me where am going wrong @SanyamJain

Comment: Have posted the full code, please go through and do let me know if anything else is required

Comment: @TRINACHAUDHURI now having seen the full code, Niraj's answer is looking more correct, it doesn't look like you ever initialise `product` in the state? You say it should be parsed by the API response but I see nowhere that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined or initialized product._id, you have to set value for product._id because it is trying to read value.

Please add like this in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        data: [],
        likeIcon: 'white',
        product:{_id:null}

    };

  }
```

Comment: As much as this *may* be the case, it's nothing more than a guess at this point.

Comment: product id should be parsed from the api

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a grave mistake of not calling the exact id which is inside the array of product inside JSON, when I called likewise, it turned to work for me, will post below the working module now:

```
onButtonPress = async() => {
    if (this.state.buttonColor == "white") {
     fetch("some url",{
       method:"POST",
       headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       body:JSON.stringify({
         "args":{
           "product":[
             "_id"
           ],
           "limit":1
         }
       })
     })
     .then((res)=>res.text())
     .then((responseJson)=>{
       this.setState({buttonColor : "red"});
     })
     .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
    });
    }
  };
```

Thank you for all your help, am glad to have got help and rectify my mistake.